# reverse string using c using pointers?

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse string using pointers and not using standard library.

Can someone please tell why is this not working?

```
int main()
{
    int length_str;
    char str[50];
    char *rev;
    fgets(str,50,stdin);
    length_str = find_length(str);
    printf("length of string is : %d",length_str);
    reverse_string(str,rev);
    puts(rev);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void reverse_string(char *str,char *rev)
{
    int length_str=find_length(str);
    while(length_str!=0)
    {
        *rev=*(str+length_str-1);
        rev++;
        length_str--;
    }
    *rev='\0';
}
```

Comment: `reverse_string(str,rev);` rev is not set

Comment: `*rev=*(str+length_str-1);`, when `rev` is not initialized

Comment: You should add a comment to the function reverse_string that describes the interface. What do you expect  to be passed in the two parameters? Shall the string reversed in place or do you expect a reversed copy?

Comment: change `char *rev;` to `char rev[50];`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate memory for the string `rev`     .